# It's normal that my data loading in postgresql with partitions takes too long?

Tags: database, postgresql, partitioning, partition, postgresql-14

I have a database that has to have approximately 20,000 records per day.
From 2022 to 2024.
I have created 6 partitions for each quarter of the years 2022 and 2023.
In total there are 14 million records between 2022 and 2023.
When loading 1 day's data with a python script, without partitions, it takes between 1-4 minutes, but when adding partitions it takes up to 10 minutes. This is normal? I'm afraid that adding more data will take much longer.

Is there any way to make this not take so long?

DDL principal table

```
CREATE TABLE public.orders (
    id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    "orderType" varchar(20) NULL,
    description text NULL,
    "createdDate" timestamp NULL,
    samples json NULL,
    discarded bool NULL,
    "customerId" varchar(5) NULL,
    "originId" varchar(4) NULL,
    "labTestGroups" json NULL,
    prices json NULL,
    tax varchar(1) NULL,
    status varchar(20) NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ("createdDate");
CREATE INDEX "orders_createdDate_idx" ON ONLY public.orders USING btree ("createdDate");
```

And the DDL of my partitions are like this =

```
CREATE TABLE public.orders2022_q1 PARTITION OF public.orders  FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2022-04-01 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Writing 20.000 record in 1 to 4 minutes, is imho already pretty slow. If it takes on average 2 minutes, you only write 167 records per second. We do at least 5000 per second, for single INSERT statements. When using COPY, it's closer to a 100.000 records per second but could be much more. What is it that your script is doing? And how does the DDL for the tables involved, looks like? Tables and indexes

Comment: That would be 8 partitions, not 6.  No, that speed and speed difference is not normal.  Are there indexes other than the one you show?

Comment: You data size is small; loading 20000 rows should take a second or two. My advice: Don't use an app language for an operational concern. Use the operational tools postgres provides: [`copy mytable from '/path/to/local/filename'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). When loading the entire dataset, delete indexes, load, create indexes.

Answer (score 0):

`asyncpg` could do 1M rows/s between Python and PostgreSQL [in 2016](https://magic.io/blog/asyncpg-1m-rows-from-postgres-to-python/).

These days they advertise [2M/s](https://github.com/magicstack/asyncpg#performance).

Even if you stick to `psycopg3` or `psycopg2` I'm guessing you're using now, make sure you know there are [multiple ways to do that](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#results-summary): `14'000'000` records in 2022 is `38356` a day, and if loading that takes 1-4 minutes, you're loading `160`-`640` rows a second (half that if you meant that's how much you had for both 2022 *and* 2023). That sounds like you picked the slowest, row-by-row insert method - that score sort of matches [test results in the link above](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#results-summary). The reason you're slightly below that could mean each of your rows is heavier but also that you're using string interpolation instead of parameter binding, slowing things down further. Other, although less likely reasons these days, would be that

- your `description`, `"labTestGroups"` and `prices` values are extremely long
- your network throughput is holding you back
- hardware resources on either end are exceptionally slow and scarce

Loading directly into a table will always be faster than routing records to multiple tables through the [partitioning mechanism](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) while [maintaining indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createindex.html#INDEX-RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR), but looking at your score I'd say you should be able to gain way more performance client-side.